# removing unmatching items from 2 lists in python

Tags: python, list

I need to remove all unmatching items from list1 if it does not exist in list2

```
 List1 = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird']
 List2 = ['dog']

 for x in List2:
      for y in List1:
           if x!=y:
                List1.remove(x)
```

This loop stucks after removing one item from list1.
What is the correct code for this operation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this with list comprehension:

```
list_intersection = [item for item in List1 if item in List2]
```

This will iterate over all the items in `List1` and return only the elements that are also in `List2`.

The `list_intersection` variable will now contain only element that appear in both lists ignoring the items that only appear in one of the lists.

---

If you don't mind duplicates being removed as part of this intersection process, you could convert both lists to [sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) and execute `set1.intersection( set2 )`. This will do the same thing - but remember, converting a list to a set will remove duplicates. Once you're done, you can convert the set back into a list.

```
l1 = [ 1, 1, 2, 3 ]
l2 = [ 2, 3, 4, 3 ]
l3 = set( l1 ).intersection( set( l2 ) )
l3 = list( l3 )
```

The variable `l3` will now be equal to `[2, 3]` because those are the only two element that appear in both original lists.

Comment: @Streak - that was a typo :) Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Did you think about [set()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) ??

Something like

```
set(List1) & set(List2)
```

Comment: Yea - this works great - but what about a little explanation of what's going on? You don't mention the considerations of duplicate removal when converting a list to a set - I feel that that is quite important information.

Comment: @Lix : you're right and you explained it correctly in your answer BTW, +1 :)